# Download GD-JPEG image with correct dimensions from cURL CLI

Tags: image, curl, gd, command-line-interface, dimensions

I need help in downloading a series of GD generated images with their correct dimensions.
I'm using this command in the cURL CLI to download a range of items:

```
curl "http://apl-moe-eng-www.ai-mi.jp/img/php/fitsample.php?&i_id=4[0001-9999]" -o "Clothes\4#1.jpg" --create-dirs
```

But the downloaded image's dimensions are smaller than the one shown on the website. The website's image's dimensions are 640*882, but cURL's output image's dimensions are 232*320.

[Original Image](http://apl-moe-eng-www.ai-mi.jp/img/php/fitsample.php?&i_id=40001)

[cURL Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0oRL.jpg)

Why is this, and can anything be added to the command to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it was because I left out a user agent:

```
curl "http://apl-moe-eng-www.ai-mi.jp/img/php/fitsample.php?&i_id=4[0001-9999]" -o "Clothes\4#1.jpg" --create-dirs --user-agent "Android"
```

Odd, huh?